# Can you integrate an LVDS with a common RS485 if the RS485 is used as a discrete and not a digital serial signal?

Tags: signal, rs485, lvds

Is the LVDS compatible with an RS485 signal? Can i integrate 2 systems in this way?

Comment: A bit more detail is needed. Are you looking to use RS485 cabling as a transport for LVDS? LVDS cabling to carry RS485? Over short or long distances? At what bitrate? With what further constraints that we may have missed?

Comment: Subsystem A will accept the LVDS signal from Subsystem B and send it to Subsystem C. Are the drivers for RS485 compatible enough to do this?

Comment: You can send it but can you decode it? Is it just a monitor ?  Discrete is not related

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by compatibility? If your LVDS bitrate is low enough and your RS485 bitrate high enough, you can convert your signals using a circuit of your design, but on the other hand, if your RS485 link isn't fast enough to keep up, or if you intend to connect LVDS signals directly into an RS485 transceiver, it won't work. Instead of single comments with a tiny bit of detail at a time, write up your entire design question, including relevant numerical values and diagrams, by [edit]ing your post.

Comment: The signal is just a discrete with no digital characteristics.

Comment: @DanH do you mean `analog`?

Answer (score 1):

While LVDS > 1Gbps and M-LVDS offer greater speeds of 100 Mbps, compared to RS-485 of 20 Mbps.  However RS-485 offers greater range and better noise immunity at the same speed but uses more power.

But you need to specify your speed and range of the interface to compare A & B.

Because LVDS peripherals might use words that are not multiples of 8 bits, it is wiser to use LVDS for short haul e.g. 10 bit LVDS Rx https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/maxim-integrated/MAX9235ETE/1702056

I recall LVDS can do much better than 2 Gbps-meter product.  Active equalization can be used.  e.g.
200 Mbps for 10 m with good eye patterns.  (but depends on SMPS CM Noise on both ends)

Comment: If long distance differential current wins over differential voltage to raise common mode impedance, so you could even consider CML  differential Current Mode Logic